# Mobile Menu not showing in Twiitter Bootstrap webpage

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Webpage</title>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <![endif]-->

    <!-- CSS
  ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <a class="brand" href="#">La Estación Argentina</a>
        <div class="nav-collapse">
          <ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Nosotros</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Menú</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Galería</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Ubicación</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Promociones</a></li>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="span9"></div>
      <div class="span3">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the code, with the CSS Applied gives us this result when "shinking" the page (responsiveness works flawlessly):

[image: SampleImagen]

But when clicking the button to show the menu elments on mobile, it doesn't show anything, (but the full-width page does have menu elements) Why is this happening?

Comment: Have you got a working version of this we can see? If you are testing this on your desktop make sure that your jQuery is getting loaded as I imagine the click event just isn't firing.

Comment: Here it is the working example: http://eargentina.wavessenger.appspot.com/ and no, it doesn't work either u.u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the function to operate the menu is relying on the jQuery library.

Check out this JSBin example where the library has been included and it is working fine, http://jsbin.com/itutin/1/